# Average If function - Exclude Zero?

Tags: excel

I am using the following averageIf formula

```
=AVERAGEIF('Backend Data - Aerospace'!D:D, "Total",'Backend Data - Aerospace'!E:E)
```

However, it is counting 0's and i do not want this.
Is there a way i can exclude 0's from being calculated as part of the average?

Thanks

Comment: If you're on Excel 2007 or higher, look into `AVERAGEIFS`

Comment: `=AVERAGEIFS('Backend Data - Aerospace'!E:E,'Backend Data - Aerospace'!D:D, "Total",'Backend Data - Aerospace'!E:E,"<>0")`  like @tigeravatar said if 2007 and later.

Comment: @ScottCraner excellent thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To exclude zero values, you'd use the criteria `<>0`.

`=AVERAGEIFS('Backend Data - Aerospace'!E:E,'Backend Data - Aerospace'!D:D, "Total",'Backend Data - Aerospace'!E:E,"<>0")`

If you need a formula that doesn't ignore empty cells or if you're still using Excel 2003, you can use a formula in the following format:

`=SUM(range)/COUNTIF(range,"<>0")`

Comment: Right, but it also has to include the original requirement of the word "Total" in column D

Comment: yup just like my comment.